# cannot implicitly convert type class to another class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, implicit-conversion

Console Application :  I have one object which has all ticket details, I am trying to pass this object through webservice.

Basically, I want assign "VVV" (list of ticket details values) to "APTR" object then, i will pass "APTR" to the method.

Console Application :

```
   public string SendAllticketDetailsToService(AutoProvisionWebAPIClient.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse vvv)
    {                         
        // bool result = false;
        string xmlStringResult;
        xmlStringResult = ""; 
        try
        {        
            AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse APTR = new AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse();
```

I want assign vvv class object values to APTR, Can you guide me ?

```
            xmlStringResult = ss.GetAllTickets(APTR);

            Console.WriteLine(xmlStringResult); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
       return xmlStringResult;           
    }
    //end
```

Both are different namespaces but the same class and attributes..   when i tried to compile, i am getting the error like

> Error 55  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'AutoProvisionWebAPIClient.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse' to
>   'AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse' 
>   \ARMWebAPIClient\AutoProvisionController\SRMUserRegServiceProxy.cs    44  24  AutoProvisionController

Comment: what type of service are you using?  You might look into this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653(v=vs.100).aspx or use something like automapper to copy the values from one object to another.

Answer (score 2):

If they are two classes within two different namespaces, they are essentially treated as two different classes even if they have the same attributes and methods.

You should use a common namespace to define the class, and use it instead.

**EDIT**

If you MUST use two different namespaces (although I don't see why), you could individually copy attributes of one class objects to the other, which is the same idea as the one suggested in the other answer.

```
namespace NamespaceOne
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NamespaceTwo
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MainNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            NamespaceOne.Person p1 = new NamespaceOne.Person() { FirstName = "Zaphod", LastName = "Beeblebrox" };
            NamespaceTwo.Person p2 = new NamespaceTwo.Person() { FirstName = p1.FirstName, LastName = p1.LastName };

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this is really pointless and I advice against it. Correct approach is to have just one common namespace in which your class (in this case, `Person`) resides, and use it when needed. Like so:

```
namespace CommonNamespace
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MainNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            CommonNamespace.Person p1 = new CommonNamespace.Person() { FirstName = "Zaphod", LastName = "Beeblebrox" };
            CommonNamespace.Person p2 = p1;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the classes are within two different assemblies, then create a 3rd project (Class Library) to hold these common classes and reference this class library from both the web service and console app.

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to go. And in addition, if these needs to be sent over web servers and the like, serialization will likely be needed as well.

Comment: Yes , You are correct. WebService + Console application both are invoking same dll (namespace + class)  AutoProvisionWebAPIClient.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse , but when i tried to pass "vvv" to the ss.GetAllTickets(vvv) method. I am getting error.  Thats the reason, I created new instance for WebService class like 
 AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse  APTR = new AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse();

Comment: Error 56 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AutoProvisionWebAPIClient.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse' to 'AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse'

Comment: Like we said, it is because those two classes are _different_ despite having same attributes. You need to have one common `Namespace.Class`, and then both projects need to reference it.

Comment: Check the type of the parameter of `GetAllTickets()` method, If you're passing an object of the correct type, the compiler shouldn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

> Both are different namespaces but the same class and attributes

That means both are completely different classes.

One solution is to have a a single class (perhaps in yet another namespace both assemblies use) for both cases.

Another is to create a translation method that creates takes an `AutoProvisionWebAPIClient.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse` and returns an `AutoProvisionController.SRMUserRegServiceReference.AutoProvisionTicketsResponse` built by examining the argument's members and assigning to the created object.

Possibly this could be a casting operator defined in one of those casts, which would allow a cast rather than a method call to be used.